# How to sort order in Survival analysis in R

Tags: r

I have big data (n=500,000) on which I want to make survival analysis.

I believe I have been able to get the regression as below.

```
# your custom theme; unchanged
custom_theme <- function(){
  theme_survminer() %+replace%
    theme(
      legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"),
      plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.4)
    )
}

# Create the formula
filtered_data$event <- filtered_data$match_MACE
filtered_data$event_followup <- filtered_data$time_diff_MACE_months
formula1 <- as.formula("Surv(event_followup, event) ~ score")

# Fit Cox proportional hazards model with reference group
cox1 <- coxph(Surv(event_followup, event) ~ relevel(score, ref = "no AF proc + inactive"), data = filtered_data)

cox1 <- coxph(formula1, data = filtered_data)

coxP1 <- data.frame(summary(cox1)$coefficients)[,5]

# Generate the confidence intervals and p-values with renamed scores
coxConf1 <- data.frame(summary(cox1)$conf.int) %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  mutate(p = coxP1,
         p2 = case_when(
           round(p, 3) > p ~ '=',
           round(p, 3) < p ~ '=',
           round(p, 3) == p ~ '='
         ),
         p3 = ifelse(round(p, 2) == 1, T, F),
         tag = paste0(rowname %>% gsub("(\\D)(\\d)", "\\1 \\2", .),
                      ". HR ", exp.coef. %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      " (95% CI ",
                      lower..95 %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      "-", upper..95 %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      "), ",
                      ifelse(p < 0.001, "P<0.001",
                             ifelse(p >= 0.01 & p < 0.05, "P<0.05",
                                    ifelse(p >= 0.05, paste0("P", p2, sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", round(p, 2))),
                                           paste0("P", p2, sprintf(fmt = "%.3f", p))))))) %>%
  select(tag) %>%
  rename(new_variable_name = tag)

coxConf1$new_variable_name <- gsub("score", "", coxConf1$new_variable_name)

# Remove leading and trailing spaces
coxConf1$new_variable_name <- trimws(coxConf1$new_variable_name)

# Validate the result
coxConf1
```

But I am struggling to create the survival analysis plot where I will have

- the four groups, with `no AF + inactive` as the reference group
- and the reference group at the top of the legends, followed by `no AF proc + active`, then `AF proc + inactive` + `AF proc + active`.
- same order for the risk table.

At the moment, the output in the legends are not the same than the output from the cox regression, and the colour in the table are not the same than the colour in the plot.

```
# model to plot- 
###----
fit1 <- survfit(Surv(event_followup, event) ~ relevel(score, ref = "no AF proc + inactive"), data = filtered_data)

# Reorder the legend labels based on the desired order
legend_labels <- c("No AF proc + inactive", "No AF proc + active", "AF proc + inactive", "AF proc + active")

risk_table_order <- c("no AF proc + inactive", "No AF proc + active", "AF proc + inactive", "AF proc + active")

# Generate the plot with the reordered legends
uni <- ggsurvplot(fit1, 
                   test.for.trend = TRUE,
                   conf.int = FALSE,
                   censor = FALSE,
                   ggtheme = custom_theme(), 
                   legend = c(0.4, 0.25),
                   font.legend = c(size = 12),
                   legend.title = element_blank(),
                   legend.labs = c("no AF proc + inactive ", unlist(coxConf1)),
                   xlab = "Follow-up (months)",
                   font.x = c(size = 12),
                   risk.table = T,
                   risk.table.side = "left",
                   risk.table.y.text = F,
                   risk.table.title = "Risk Table",
                   risk.table.col = 1,
                   risk.table.order = risk_table_order,
                   ylab = "Free from MACE",
                   font.y = c(size = 12),
                   ylim = c(0, 1.05),
                   xlim = c(0, N * 12),
                   break.y.by = 0.2,
                   break.x.by = 6,
                   axes.offset = TRUE)

# Add the additional labels from coxConf1 to the legend
uni$plot <- uni$plot +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c(coxConf1$new_variable_name, "no AF proc + inactive"),
                     values = c("green", "blue", "orange", "red")) 

# Update the color scale in the risk table
uni$table <- uni$table +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c(coxConf1$new_variable_name, "no AF proc + inactive"),
                    values = c("green", "blue", "orange", "red"))

# Print the plot
print(uni)
```

Here are the portion of my data:

```
    Participant.ID match_MACE time_diff_MACE_months                 score
1          1169548          0                  72.0      AF proc + active
2          1098887          0                  72.0      AF proc + active
3          1064538          0                  72.0      AF proc + active
4          1089599          1                  52.8      AF proc + active
5          1151144          0                  72.0      AF proc + active
6          1195483          1                   3.9      AF proc + active
7          1188227          0                  72.0    AF proc + inactive
8          1009863          0                  72.0    AF proc + inactive
9          1081307          0                  72.0    AF proc + inactive
10         1154860          1                  24.1    AF proc + inactive
11         1032585          0                  72.0    AF proc + inactive
12         1150639          1                  41.6    AF proc + inactive
13         1162966          1                  10.0    AF proc + inactive
14         1036817          1                  38.9    AF proc + inactive
15         1110369          1                  37.1    AF proc + inactive
16         1224730          0                  72.0    AF proc + inactive
17         1081741          1                   1.6   no AF proc + active
18         1151938          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
19         1094579          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
20         1099578          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
21         1103712          1                  18.7   no AF proc + active
22         1165594          1                  11.7   no AF proc + active
23         1112693          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
24         1212915          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
25         1098520          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
26         1199539          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
27         1032596          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
28         1081820          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
29         1182095          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
30         1080136          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
31         1168550          1                  18.0   no AF proc + active
32         1112211          1                   5.9   no AF proc + active
33         1099400          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
34         1150138          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
35         1169589          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
36         1130930          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
37         1023969          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
38         1148484          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
39         1122955          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
40         1156431          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
41         1019486          1                  11.7   no AF proc + active
42         1071958          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
43         1108366          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
44         1204170          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
45         1004705          1                  28.4   no AF proc + active
46         1118320          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
47         1029092          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
48         1124181          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
49         1215341          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
50         1198926          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
51         1011130          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
52         1025778          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
53         1158451          1                   1.2   no AF proc + active
54         1138223          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
55         1060529          1                  49.9   no AF proc + active
56         1152697          1                  66.6   no AF proc + active
57         1053224          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
58         1049995          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
59         1010349          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
60         1038676          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
61         1113027          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
62         1173430          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
63         1197104          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
64         1084089          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
65         1056039          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
66         1016849          1                  11.4   no AF proc + active
67         1085906          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
68         1069267          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
69         1088756          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
70         1169474          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
71         1212484          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
72         1160969          1                   2.1   no AF proc + active
73         1110720          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
74         1159911          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
75         1193184          1                   2.6   no AF proc + active
76         1214083          1                  34.5   no AF proc + active
77         1039295          1                  49.8   no AF proc + active
78         1220844          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
79         1103750          1                   5.9   no AF proc + active
80         1155089          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
81         1030976          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
82         1015095          1                  68.9   no AF proc + active
83         1209639          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
84         1221353          1                   3.0   no AF proc + active
85         1115244          1                  20.4   no AF proc + active
86         1102645          1                   9.3   no AF proc + active
87         1141749          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
88         1167528          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
89         1136411          1                  24.0   no AF proc + active
90         1076923          1                   3.6   no AF proc + active
91         1220060          1                   9.3   no AF proc + active
92         1217955          1                  13.5   no AF proc + active
93         1024327          1                  16.8   no AF proc + active
94         1161868          1                  30.6   no AF proc + active
95         1164625          1                  55.5   no AF proc + active
96         1044532          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
97         1051373          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
98         1010462          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
99         1064218          1                  16.4   no AF proc + active
100        1164728          1                  20.9   no AF proc + active
101        1193872          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
102        1065997          1                  27.0   no AF proc + active
103        1018197          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
104        1078482          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
105        1140958          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
106        1212470          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
107        1045422          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
108        1159452          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
109        1063314          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
110        1081265          1                  40.8   no AF proc + active
111        1177440          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
112        1156121          1                   8.0   no AF proc + active
113        1148416          0                  72.0   no AF proc + active
114        1170157          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
115        1169467          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
116        1039020          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
117        1116305          1                  68.5 no AF proc + inactive
118        1036116          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
119        1000414          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
120        1101961          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
121        1128884          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
122        1079375          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
123        1083593          1                   3.4 no AF proc + inactive
124        1017198          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
125        1184712          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
126        1006604          1                  59.4 no AF proc + inactive
127        1202283          1                  22.6 no AF proc + inactive
128        1197594          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
129        1145799          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
130        1072222          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
131        1168984          1                  14.0 no AF proc + inactive
132        1134637          1                  10.1 no AF proc + inactive
133        1119639          1                  25.4 no AF proc + inactive
134        1082634          1                  69.0 no AF proc + inactive
135        1174344          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
136        1020621          1                   7.8 no AF proc + inactive
137        1024878          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
138        1068864          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
139        1115700          1                  45.6 no AF proc + inactive
140        1075462          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
141        1173856          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
142        1162017          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
143        1131283          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
144        1204985          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
145        1024645          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
146        1221414          1                   1.3 no AF proc + inactive
147        1207542          1                  30.4 no AF proc + inactive
148        1002733          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
149        1158465          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
150        1214236          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
151        1099718          1                   6.8 no AF proc + inactive
152        1032299          1                  62.3 no AF proc + inactive
153        1062237          1                  25.1 no AF proc + inactive
154        1180813          1                   7.7 no AF proc + inactive
155        1112010          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
156        1098256          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
157        1223290          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
158        1140145          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
159        1082226          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
160        1092734          1                  39.6 no AF proc + inactive
161        1057267          1                  18.8 no AF proc + inactive
162        1199418          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
163        1143094          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
164        1192641          1                  56.8 no AF proc + inactive
165        1215091          1                   8.0 no AF proc + inactive
166        1201176          1                  37.9 no AF proc + inactive
167        1217497          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
168        1026150          1                  26.1 no AF proc + inactive
169        1092164          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
170        1222354          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
171        1200144          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
172        1154902          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
173        1163901          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
174        1085890          1                  28.1 no AF proc + inactive
175        1184176          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
176        1068718          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
177        1221825          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
178        1124417          1                  18.5 no AF proc + inactive
179        1080766          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
180        1197133          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
181        1152678          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
182        1049669          1                  26.4 no AF proc + inactive
183        1046175          1                  13.0 no AF proc + inactive
184        1094515          1                  59.9 no AF proc + inactive
185        1066319          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
186        1167031          1                   4.0 no AF proc + inactive
187        1099812          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
188        1118674          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
189        1216340          1                  24.3 no AF proc + inactive
190        1060200          1                  24.0 no AF proc + inactive
191        1055191          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
192        1093435          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
193        1164844          1                  67.0 no AF proc + inactive
194        1220734          1                  12.0 no AF proc + inactive
195        1171966          0                  72.0 no AF proc + inactive
196        1024115          1                   1.7 no AF proc + inactive
197        1143227          1                  11.3 no AF proc + inactive
198        1021282          1                   1.5 no AF proc + inactive
199        1101307          1                  37.9 no AF proc + inactive
200        1191745          1                  64.3 no AF proc + inactive
```